# Django rest framework not encrypting passwords, when being logged into the database

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, basic-authentication, django-authentication

So I am using Django's (1.7 with postgres) Rest Api (Django REST framework 3.0.2) with basic authentication to register and authenticate users for my mobile test app. The problem is that the users I create through the admin panel get their passwords encrypted, however when I create users, using the rest-framework into the same "User" (default) database, the passwords do not get encrypted. This is causing us several problems (especially to validate a user to get a token from api-token-auth). Is there something I can do? Perhaps something in the settings? (We are also running gunicorn and ngnix on our server). 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you're just using a ModelSerializer and a ModelViewSet. You're going to have to override your ModelSerializer's create method.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        username=validated_data['username']
    )
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user
```

The ModelSerializer's [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-additional-keyword-arguments-for-fields) have an example that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do that

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        username=validated_data['username']
    )
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user
```